# Plotting a single point (x, y, z) in three dimensional space using R

Tags: r

I am trying to plot one single (x, y, z) point in 3 dimensional space, similar to the graph here:
[image: Example 3d graph]

I have tried using the `scatter3d` function from the `rgl` library, however I am stuck over how to get the point itself. I tried the following:

```
scatter3d(x=-4, y=0, z=-1)
```

which resulted in:
[image: Result]

I am not sure how to structure the data to get the point. Is there another library that I could use which is better suited for this? Or am I using this function the wrong way?

Comment: Have a lok at [this article](http://www.r-bloggers.com/getting-fancy-with-3-d-scatterplots/), it contains some useful examples for getting 3D scatter plots.

Comment: You probably want `library(scatterplot3d); scatterplot3d(x=-4, y=0, z=-1)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reproduce your first plot

```
library(rgl)
x=2
y=3
z=1
plot3d(x, y, z, col = rainbow(1000), xlim = c(-4,4), ylim = c(-4, 4), zlim = c(-2, 2))
abclines3d(2, 3, 1, a = diag(3), col = "gray")
```

[image]

Comment: How did you get the graph slanted? I put this exact code into the R terminal and got a forward facing cube.

Comment: I use X-quartz (Mac) so it's interactive, you move the box like you want

Comment: don't forget to accept the answer if it suits you :-)